# All files in every folder of a network drive

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking for a vbs or .bat that will find every file in every folder within a network drive then dump it in a .csv file.

I need to capture the fodler/file name, created date (not modified date), and file owner.

I ahve a simple batch that picks up the file name and path, it's really the creation date and file owner that i'm having a hard time with.

If anyone could help, that would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'm using `code`dir /s "Star"."Star" /q /tc > C:\File.csv. Now i just need to figure out how to format the CSV file.

Comment: You can strip the wildcard in the `dir` command :)

Comment: @user3298684, add your code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you mostly to what you're looking for. Folder owner isn't part of the [Folder object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), so you'll need to have a [separate](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/07/how-can-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-file.aspx) [function](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/security/ownership/scr_1386.asp) for that.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
OUTPUT_FILE = "Temp.csv"

Call findFiles(objFSO.GetFolder("Z:\Completed\Misc"))

Sub findFiles(objFolder)

  For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    Call findFiles (objSubFolder)
  Next

  Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

  For Each objFile In objFiles    
    writeFile objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name & "," & objFile.DateCreated 
  Next 
End Sub

Sub writeFile(strText)
  Dim objFSO, objLogFile

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
  Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OUTPUT_FILE, 8, True)

  objLogFile.WriteLine strText    
  objLogFile.Close

  Set objLogFile = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that seems like it'll get most of what i want!